# Django Query - best way to write query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have models like following

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    airwaybill_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ShipmentHistory(Models.Model):
    airwaybill_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_added_bag = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    some other fields which can be null
```

Which one of the following is the best way to update a row in ShipmentHistory table.

**Using try / except**

```
try:
    history = ShipmentHistory.objects.get(airwaybill_number=1000)
    history.last_added_bag = 'abc'
    # update other history fields
    history.save()
except ShipmentHistory.DoesNotExist:
    # create the history record and then update
```

**Using query filter**

```
history = ShipmentHistory.objects.filter(airwaybill_number=1000)
if history.exists()
    history[0].last_added_bag = 'abc'
    # update other fields
    history[0].save()
else:
    # create history record first then update
```

The history records for a particular shipment will be updated atleast a dozen times.

1. Do any of the methods have advantages over others, or is there a better way to do this?
2. Is using a try / except a wrong method of implementation?
3. Is the query filter option a more expensive query with regards to time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `Queryset.get_or_create()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
history, created = ShipmentHistory.objects.get_or_create(airwaybill_number=1000)
# update the fields and save..
```

Answer (score 2):

i have never seen a django model defined like this, i hope, this is only pseudo one

```
Shipment:
   airwaybill_number (pk)
   origin (not null)
   destination (not null)
```

and your both queries are two different queries. `.get()` vs `.filter()`. the later one gives you queryset whereas `.get()` gives you an object.

for `.get()` you dont have much options to optimize, but you could use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) instead of try/catch. the problem with `get()` in your case is you could get [MultipleObjectsReturned](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned) if there are more than one. thats why i would go for the one with filter().

and yes, `.exists()` is cheaper than `.count()`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I have updated the psuedo code with original code.